# Get path between tags using sed or awk

Tags: parsing, sed, awk

I want to get **path** (/tmp/deployment/deployment/hostVBox_8080_GSA/) from ps output:

```
username@hostVBox:~$ps ax |grep jboss
16291 pts/4    Sl     0:34 java -Dprogram.name=run.sh -Xms128m -Xmx512m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/tmp/deployment/deployment/hostVBox_8080_GSA/lib/endorsed -classpath /tmp/deployment/deployment/hostVBox_8080_GSA/bin/run.jar:/lib/tools.jar org.jboss.Main
```

How can I do that?

BR
Kolesar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
echo "a bunch of stuff ... -classpath /tmp/deployment/deployment/hostVBox_8080_GSA/bin/run.jar:/lib/tools.jar org.jboss.Main' |
sed -e 's#.*-classpath \(\([^/]*/\)*\)bin/run.jar.*#\1#'
/tmp/deployment/deployment/hostVBox_8080_GSA/
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

Command:

```
awk -F"dirs=" '
    /java/{
        a=$2
        split(a,path," -")
        sub(/[^/]*\/[^/]*$/,"",path[1])
        print path[1]
    }'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, see if it works:

```
ps ax |grep jboss|awk -F'java.endorsed.dirs=' '{gsub(/lib.*/,"",$2);print $2;exit;}'
```